# Postgresql - Get Distinct Records on the basis of Json Values

Tags: php, sql, json, postgresql, distinct

> Scenario: I have table having the value stored in Json format on its
>   one of the column.I'm expecting the result to get the Distinct or
>   Unique Records on the basis of value (one of the value of json column
>   value) stored in format of json.

```
My table have 3 columns :
1. Id (integer) 
ex. value - 20
2. Description (text) 
ex.value - {"first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","company_id":"26"}
3. Created (integer)
```

Now i want the Distinct records on the basis of **company_id** value and Is there any function available in PostgreSQL for such requirements ?

**Technical Info :**

> Postgresql version - 9.5

Comment: You can use [DISTINCT ON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) `select distinct on (ex.value ->> 'company_id')` (or `select distinct on (ex.value -> 'company_id')` if you have `jsonb`), but the values in other columns are not guaranteed (unless you supply additional `order by` expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres 9.5 (as well as a few earlier versions) has some built-in support for querying JSON text.  Try the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE Description->>'company_id' = 'some_value'
```

[**Documentation**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html)